# Auto alignment of buttons in toolbar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a way to have a toolbar (stock/custom) which aligns all buttons together to one side, say, left?

I have 3 buttons, `a`,`b`,`c` on toolbar. If i dynamically make `b` hidden, then there is a visible gap between `a` and `c`. How can I have a toolbar which automatically closes gap between `a` and `c` together, but restores the order when `b` becomes visible again?

Thanks!

## Info

I have tried `<Toolbar />`, `<Stackpanel />`, `<DockPanel />` so far, but they did not align the buttons.

Comment: make b `Collapsed` instead of `Hidden`

Comment: @Bolu, your answer worked!!!!! Please put it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make b `Collapsed` instead of `Hidden`

Refer to MSDN [UIElement.Visibility Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> In the WPF model, Hidden denotes a visibility state where the object
>   should not render, but should still occupy space in a WPF layout.

And more specific, as @Nayan pointed out, can refer to [`Visibility Enumeration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx):

> - Collapsed Do not display the element, and do not reserve space for it in layout.
> - Hidden    Do not display the element, but reserve space for the element in layout.
> - Visible   Display the element.

**PS**: That is why for [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx):

> The Convert method returns Visibility.Visible when true is passed in or Visibility.Collapsed when false is passed in.

Comment: please share the link to this documentation as well. Thx!

Comment: Thx! This is what I wanted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx

Comment: @Nayan this part is now included into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Width="100" Click="Button_Click" />
    <Button Width="100" Click="Button_Click" />
    <Button Width="100" Click="Button_Click" />
    <Button Width="100" Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? It doesn't work. The gap is still visible.